# How do I set the Manager Attribute on the UserPrincipal object in Active Directory in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to set the attribute `Manager` on an object of type `UserPrincipal` documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680857(v=vs.85).aspx

but cannot simply say

```
UserPrincipal.Manager = "some value"
```

Can someone please explain to me how this works? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The basic `UserPrincipal` in the S.DS.AM namespace does not feature that attribute - but you can extend the user principal class and add additional attributes that you need.

Read more about it here:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
(*there's a section on **extensibility** towards the end of the article*)

Here's the code:

```
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("Person")]
public class UserPrincipalEx : UserPrincipal
{
    // Inplement the constructor using the base class constructor. 
    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context) : base(context)
    { }

    // Implement the constructor with initialization parameters.    
    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context,
                         string samAccountName,
                         string password,
                         bool enabled) : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled)
    {} 

    // Create the "Manager" property.    
    [DirectoryProperty("manager")]
    public string Manager
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("manager").Length != 1)
                return string.Empty;

            return (string)ExtensionGet("manager")[0];
        }
        set { ExtensionSet("manager", value); }
    }

    // Implement the overloaded search method FindByIdentity.
    public static new UserPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, string identityValue)
    {
        return (UserPrincipalEx)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalEx), identityValue);
    }

    // Implement the overloaded search method FindByIdentity. 
    public static new UserPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, string identityValue)
    {
        return (UserPrincipalEx)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalEx), identityType, identityValue);
    }
}
```

Now you can find and work with a `UserPrincipalEx` class which has the `.Manager` property for you to use:

```
UserPrincipalEx userEx = UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourUserName");

// the .Manager property contains the DN (distinguished name) for the manager of this user
var yourManager = userEx.Manager;
```

Comment: I assume I have to do this for every Attribute that is not a "standard" part of the UserPrincipal class such as Email address or custom attributes like WorkCellPhone?

Comment: @user574376: yes - but of course, you can have one class `UserPrincipalEx` that contains all those attributes - that's what I have, the code above is just a small section from my real class.

Comment: There isn't an easier way of doing this? Like by calling PropertiesToLoad when I search for the initial UserPrincipal object? This seems like a lot of work to go through.

Comment: If you don't want to subclass `UserPrincipal`, then you need to look into using `DirectorySearcher` and `DirectoryEntry`.

Comment: @user574376: no - deriving from `UserPrincipal` is the defined extensibility mechanism - and it's really not that hard! Just try it!

Comment: +1 But what about directReports? I am trying to get this to work for the directReports attribute but the call is failing with "constraint violation exception!" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882196/assigning-multiple-value-property-directreports-using-system-directoryservices

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I love the example but totally get where the RatBoyStl is coming from. Sometimes you just want a value and not a new class.

If you have a `UserPrinciple` object for a given user then you can easily retrieve the manager property with this code. I took it a step futher and used the manager value to find their `UserPrinciple` and display the email address.

```
            //set the principal context to the users domain
        PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, userDomain);

        //lookup the user id on the domain
        UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, userId);
        if (up == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("AD USER NOT FOUND {0}", userGc));
            return;

        }

        //grab the info we need from the domain
        Console.WriteLine(up.ToString());

        DirectoryEntry d = up.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
        string managerCN = d.Properties["manager"].Value.ToString(); 
        Console.WriteLine(managerCN);

        UserPrincipal manager = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, managerCN);
        Console.WriteLine(manager.EmailAddress);
```

Comment: I've had terrible luck getting the PrincipalEx Save to actually save in Active Directory, but the GetUnderlyingObject() method simplifies using the old way of setting Properties[X]...  Thank you.