# Assigning multiple value property 'directReports' using System.DirectoryServices Active Directory APIs

Tags: c#, active-directory

My initial attempts to assign multiple values as directReports to a user in Active Directory were to use DirectoryEntry objects and assign as follows:

```
DirectoryEntry de; //get it from somewhere
de.Properties["directReports"].Value = object[] { "CN=user123,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=xyz", "dn2", "dn3" };
de.CommitChanges(); //error: contraint violation occurred
```

It also didn't work for the "manager" attribute.

I then started to use UserPrincipal extension methods (which use DirectoryEntries in the background, right?)

```
    [DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
    [DirectoryObjectClass("Person")]
    public class UserPrincipalEx : UserPrincipal
    {
        public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext pc)
            : base(pc)
        {
        }

        public void SetManager(string value)
        {
            this.ExtensionSet("manager", value);
        }

        public void SetDirectReports(string[] values)
        {
            //foreach(var v in values)
            this.ExtensionSet("directReports", values);
        }

        public static new UserPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, string identityValue)
        {
            return (UserPrincipalEx)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalEx), identityValue);
        }

        public static new UserPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, string identityValue)
        {
            return (UserPrincipalEx)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalEx), identityType, identityValue);
        }
    }
```

Assigning a manager by sending a distinguished name string works fine, but it doesn't work for direct reports. I still get `InvalidOperationException: A constraint violation occurred.`

I'm trying to call it like this:

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mazen", user, pass);
UserPrincipalEx up = UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "moses");
var dns = new string[] { "CN=someone,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=xyz", "CN=anotherone,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=xyz" };
up.SetDirectReports(dns);
```

How can one assign the direct reports multi-value property using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `directReports` is a **calculated** field in Active Directory.

If you have 10 employees with the same manager, then that manager's `directReports` property will list all those 10 employees.

But you **cannot** directly set that property yourself - you have to set the employee's `manager` property, and then the manager's `directReports` property will be set automatically by Active Directory

Comment: I read "This attribute contains the list of users that directly report to the user. The users that are listed as reports are those that have the property manager property set to this user. Each item in the list is a linked reference to the object that represents the user." on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221482.aspx but could not have guessed what you say. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: I am guessing that there is a delay before the directReports attributes are added to an entry (after the manager attribute is added on the subordinate). Any idea how long? You made my day with your answer, very much appreciated!!!